# Wooden gate drags when opening

Tags: fence, gates

The door has been sanded and works for the summer season. When it rains the wood swells and the door drags. Does the door need to be rehung?

Comment: I solved a similar problem with a turnbuckle attached to the dragging corner and to the diagonally opposite hinge plate. It is adjustable in case the door should sag further with time.

Comment: Is this a door or a gate? Is it outdoors?

Comment: Door or outdoor gate ?   It may not ( probably not )  be because the wood is swelling but because the post it is attached to is moving with seasonal ground temperature fluctuations. Or as Phil suggest the unit is sagging.  Does the gap between the side of the gate and the post it closes to change?  You can have the bottom of the gate trimmed. More info or photos would help to get an appropriate answer as to fixing your problem.

Comment: A picture would sure help.

Comment: @phil Freedenberg, make that an answer, I have the same many times.